# Creating Grid View in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am facing difficulty in creating grid view for my table whose data is coming from database as a response in JSON format. Both UI and Javascript code are in same file. I have installed ng-grid using npm package at root path of application.

Index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui.grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="ng-grid-2.0.11.min.js"></script>

 <table style="width:50%" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Select</th>
           <th>FR_ID</th>
           <th>FR_Client</th>
           <th>FR_Source</th>
           <th>FR_Destination</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="search in searches">
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>{{search.id}}</td>
            <td>{{search.client}}</td>
            <td>{{search.source}}</td>
            <td>{{search.destination}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

   </table>
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                    <div class="submitButton" id="submitButton" ng-app="searchapp">
                        <div style="visibility:hidden;">{{y=name}}</div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="seachRecords(y)" style="font-size:20px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Angular:

```
     <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

             $scope.seachRecords = function (y) {
                var httpRequest = $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/user/search?seachString='+y,

                }).then(function (response, status) {

                    var responsetest = JSON.stringify(response.data);

                    $scope.searches = response.data;

                }, function myError(data, status) {
                    $scope.searches = data;     
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I am able to create below table as shown in the image attached but I am trying to get Grid view and not able to form it, please suggest changes required for this.

[image]

Comment: Does ng-grid support using tables? http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/ doesn't have any examples using tables. Also you'd need to use `ng-grid` instead of `ng-repeat`

Comment: did you check if you got any console errors?Can you share a plunkr or js fiddle of the code? Also ng-grid is an outdated one so I may ask you to prefer uigrid.

Comment: how I can use uigrid in this.I have installed ui-grid using npm

Comment: @Akurn : Please add an appropriate link. The link you shared is opening error page(i.e. 404 pqage not found)

Answer (score 0):

JSON data should be usable with grid view as follows

```
<div data-ng-grid="searches"></div>
```

NOTE: 'responsetest' variable appears to be unused.

The response could be attached to 'searches' directly. Grid view expects a 'data' property to access searches data.

Angular

```
$scope.searches = JSON.stringify(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

HTML:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui.grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="ng-grid-2.0.11.min.js"></script>

<div ng-grid="searches"></div>

<div class="small-12 columns">
  <div class="submitButton" id="submitButton" ng-app="searchapp">
      <div style="visibility:hidden;">{{y=name}}</div>

      <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="seachRecords(y)" style="font-size:20px" />
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
       $scope.seachRecords = function (y) {
          var httpRequest = $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: '/user/search?seachString='+y,

          }).then(function (response, status) {

              var responsetest = JSON.stringify(response.data);

              $scope.searches = {
                data: response.data
              }

          });
      }
    });
</script>
```

Following ng-grid implementation: 
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/

Comment: The link you added shows error page. It says : 404(Page not found)